# Multi-index dataframe split and stack

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, multi-index, yfinance

When I download data from yfinance, I get 8 columns (Open, High, Low, etc...) per ticker. Since I am downloading 15 tickers, I have 120 columns and 1 index column (date). They add up horizontally. See image 1

Instead of having that many columns, in 2 levels, I want just the 8 unique columns. Plus creating one new column that identifies the ticker. See Image 2.

[Image 1: Current Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9EQz.png)

Image 1 but in raw text:

```
    Adj Close   ... Volume
DANHOS13.MX FCFE18.MX   FHIPO14.MX  FIBRAHD15.MX    FIBRAMQ12.MX    FIBRAPL14.MX    FIHO12.MX   FINN13.MX   FMTY14.MX   FNOVA17.MX  ... FIBRAPL14.MX    FIHO12.MX   FINN13.MX   FMTY14.MX   FNOVA17.MX  FPLUS16.MX  FSHOP13.MX  FUNO11.MX   FVIA16.MX   TERRA13.MX
Date                                                                                    
2015-01-02  26.065336   NaN 18.526043   NaN 16.337654   18.520781   14.683501   11.301384   9.247743    NaN ... 338697  189552  148064  57  NaN NaN 212451  2649823 NaN 1111343
2015-01-05  24.670488   NaN 18.436762   NaN 15.857328   17.859756   13.795850   11.071105   9.209846    NaN ... 449555  364819  244594  19330   NaN NaN 491587  3317923 NaN 1255128
```

[Image 2: Desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeJTv.png)

The code Im applying is:

```
start = dt.datetime(2015,1,1)
end = dt.datetime.now()

df = yf.download("FUNO11.MX FIBRAMQ12.MX FIHO12.MX DANHOS13.MX FINN13.MX FSHOP13.MX TERRA13.MX FMTY14.MX FIBRAPL14.MX FHIPO14.MX FIBRAHD15.MX FPLUS16.MX FVIA16.MX FNOVA17.MX FCFE18.MX", 
                start = start,
                end = end,
                group_by = 'Ticker',
                actions = True)
```

Comment: can you please remove reference to links in the question and instead post the raw data as text as part of the question. Links can get broken over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will download the data a little differently:

```
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

start = dt(2015,1,1)
end = dt.now()
symbols = ["FUNO11.MX", "FIBRAMQ12.MX", "FIHO12.MX", "DANHOS13.MX", "FINN13.MX", "FSHOP13.MX", "TERRA13.MX", "FMTY14.MX",
           "FIBRAPL14.MX", "FHIPO14.MX", "FIBRAHD15.MX", "FPLUS16.MX", "FVIA16.MX", "FNOVA17.MX", "FCFE18.MX"]

data = yf.download(symbols, start=start, end=end, actions=True)
```

And then
Option 1:

```
def reshaper(symb, dframe):
    df = dframe.unstack().reset_index()
    df.columns = ['variable','symbol','Date','Value']
    df = df.loc[df.symbol==symb,['Date','variable','Value']].pivot_table(index='Date', columns='variable', values='Value').reset_index()
    df.columns.name = ''
    df['Ticker'] = symb
    return df


h = pd.DataFrame()

for s in symbols:
    h = h.append(reshaper(s, data), ignore_index=True)
    
h
```

[image]

Option 2: For a one-liner, you could do this:

```
data.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'Ticker'})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler version relies on stacking first the two column index levels (measure and ticker) to get long form tidy data, and then stack on the measure level, keeping ticker and date as indices:

```
import yfinance as yf

symbols = ["FUNO11.MX", "FIBRAMQ12.MX", "FIHO12.MX", "DANHOS13.MX", 
           "FINN13.MX", "FSHOP13.MX", "TERRA13.MX", "FMTY14.MX",
           "FIBRAPL14.MX", "FHIPO14.MX", "FIBRAHD15.MX", "FPLUS16.MX", 
           "FVIA16.MX", "FNOVA17.MX", "FCFE18.MX"]

data = yf.download(symbols, start='2015-01-01', end='2020-11-15', actions=True)

data_reshape=data.stack(level=[0,1]).unstack(1)
data_reshape.index=data_reshape.index.set_names(['ticker'],level=[1])
data_reshape.head()
```

`data_reshape.head()`

```
                         Adj Close      Close  Dividends       High  \
Date       ticker                                                     
2015-01-02 DANHOS13.MX   26.065336  37.000000        0.0  37.400002   
           FHIPO14.MX    18.526043  24.900000        0.0  24.900000   
           FIBRAMQ12.MX  16.337654  24.490000        0.0  25.110001   
           FIBRAPL14.MX  18.520781  26.740801        0.0  27.118500   
           FIHO12.MX     14.683501  21.670000        0.0  22.190001   

                               Low       Open  Stock Splits     Volume  
Date       ticker                                                       
2015-01-02 DANHOS13.MX   36.330002  36.330002           0.0    82849.0  
           FHIPO14.MX    24.900000  24.900000           0.0    94007.0  
           FIBRAMQ12.MX  24.350000  24.990000           0.0  1172917.0  
           FIBRAPL14.MX  26.343100  26.750700           0.0   338697.0  
           FIHO12.MX     21.209999  22.120001           0.0   189552.0
```